# Regex for breadcrumb to url pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have following pattern

"Parts > Home Automation & Security > DSC Alaram Package"

I want to convert it to

"Parts/Home-Automation-Security/DSC-Alaram-Package"

I can have any number of " > " in my source string.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me writing a regex or extension method in C# for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use use the [String.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) function?

```
string original = "Parts > Home Automation & Security > DSC Alaram Package";
string modified = original.Replace(" > ", "/");
```